# The letter near a digit constant in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, types

What does the letter near the digit constant mean? Just for example:

```
int number = 0;
float decimal = 2.5f;
number = decimal;
```

What's difference betweet 2.5f and f2.5 ? I have already looked in manuals, but I really cant understand it. Explaine it me please in a simple format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely as additional information (not really a direct answer to the question) I'd note that to specify the type of a character or string literal, you use a prefix (e.g., L"wide string"), whereas with a numeric literal you use a suffix (e.g., 2L or 3.5f).

C++0x adds quite a few more of both prefixes *and* suffixes to specify more data types (e.g., there are currently only narrow and wide string literals, but C++0x will have narrow, wide, Unicode, raw, and probably at least a couple more I can't think of at the moment). It also adds user-defined literals that let you define your own suffixes, so something like `150km` could be used to create a `distance` object, or `"127.0.0.1"ip` to create an `IP_address` object.

Answer (score 3):

The value 2.5 would be a double, whereas 2.5f is a float. Unless you have a specific reason not to, it is generally better to use doubles rather than floats - they are more precise and may even be faster.

Comment: Can you explain why doubles "may even be faster"?

Comment: Modern CPUs have hardware specifically for handling floating point arithmetic.  These are designed to work on doubles (actaully, on their own 80-bit format, but it's closer to doubles).  floats need to be converted to & from that.

Comment: Why then code shows me "This is: float" but not double?

float decimal = 2.5;
cout << "This is: " << typeid(decimal).name() << endl;

Comment: @Molfar 2.5 is a double, `decimal` is a float - storing a double in a float does not change the latter's type, it just loses you information.

Comment: @James Curran: that is if you define a modern CPU as x86 specifically. x64 uses SSE2, which doesn't work at 80 bit precision internally.

Comment: @jalf: really? I thought the 80-bit format wasw an IEEE standard.  Well, I come here to learn as well as teach....

Comment: @James: I think 80-bit is a IEEE standard format, yes. But CPU's aren't required to support every IEEE format. Most just support 32 and 64 bit and call it a day, SSE/SSE2 included.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfh6f0w2(VS.80).aspx):

Floating-point constants default to type double. By using the suffixes f or l (or F or L — the suffix is not case sensitive), the constant can be specified as float or long double, respectively.

I don't thing the format f2.5 is legal.

Answer (score 2):

> > What's difference betweet 2.5f and f2.5

- 2.5f is the value 2.5 as a floating point number,
- f2.5 is a variable called "f2" followed by ".5" which would be a syntax error.

Comment: Actually, that was a typo. The slash should have been a decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

`f2.5` is illegal. `2.5f` (or `2.5F`) forces 2.5 to be interpreted as a float, not as double. Relatedly, there's the `l`/`L` suffix to make integer constants `long`s.

`number = decimal` truncates the latter, I suppose.